# Horizontally Align Labels with CSS

Tags: html, css

I've got an issue that I'd love to solve by using CSS without resorting to statically sizing my labels (but perhaps it isn't possible).

I have two labels per line, one for displaying a "title" and the other for displaying the associated "value". Here's how I'd like it to look:

[image]

This is similar to [Align labels in form next to input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686538/align-labels-in-form-next-to-input) but I'm wanting the second element per line left-aligned instead of the first one to be right-aligned. I tried modifying the accepted answer from that question and set the width of the "title" label, but that has no effect on my output. As I mentioned above, I'd rather not hard-code a width anyways, but I was hoping to get something working before trying to find a good, long-term solution that can account for larger "title" values.

Here's my current CSS (the classes should be self-explanatory):

```
.propertyTitle {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 300px;/*Why doesn't this have any effect?*/
}
.propertyValue {
    text-align: left;
}
```

And my current HTML:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <label class="propertyTitle">Hello:</label>
        <label class="propertyValue">World</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label class="propertyTitle">Goodbye:</label>
        <label class="propertyValue">To All of the People in the World</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label class="propertyTitle">I Want:</label>
        <label class="propertyValue">These labels to line up</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The HTML can be modified as well, if that'd make it easier. To conform with best practices, I'd rather not use tables to make this work.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XUKx9/) showing what I have now, what am I missing? Ideally this solution would work for IE8+ and Firefox, so unfortunately HTML5 and CSS3 elements are discouraged.

**EDIT**
To reiterate after the first two answers came in (that both solve my issue), is there a way to do this without hard-coding a width for my "title" labels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

grouping your divs and labels like so:

```
<div>
    <div class="titleWrap">
        <label class="propertyTitle">Hello:</label>
        <label class="propertyTitle">Goodbye:</label>
        <label class="propertyTitle">I Want:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="valueWrap">
        <label class="propertyValue">World</label>
        <label class="propertyValue">To All of the People in the World</label>
        <label class="propertyValue">These labels to line up</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
.propertyTitle {
    display:block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: auto;
}
.titleWrap{
    display:inline-block;
}

.propertyValue {
    display:block;
    width:auto;
}
.valueWrap {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

should give you the desired result without having to specify the widths

Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XUKx9/1/)

Answer (score 1):

try using display:inline-block on your labels

```
.propertyTitle {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 300px;/*Why doesn't this have any effect?*/
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, per my update, is there a way to do this without having to set the width of my "title" labels?

Answer (score 1):

by default label is an `inline element`. that's why `width` property doesn't apply to `label`.
to apply the width you have to convert the `label` into a `block level` element by using `display:block`.

I hope it clarify the answer.

so you have to use this CSS property in your code.

```
   .propertyTitle {
     text-transform: uppercase;
    display:inline-block; /*this will make the label a block level element*/ 
    width: 300px;/*Why doesn't this have any effect?*/
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, so am I stuck setting the width of my label to make this work?

Comment: @ledbutter as per the HTML code I guess you want to make  a form.. you can use `float:left` and giving `padding` or `margin` but that will not make any impact unless you define the `width` property to `label` .. why you wan't to avoid the width property?

Comment: I want to avoid the width property so that if I get a "title" that exceeds my set width, I don't get undesired output. At the same time, I want these two labels to be spaced reasonably close together for readability.

Comment: In terms of usability you should move label to right. if you don't use width you will get this kind of results. check the Demo. http://jsbin.com/sexenuga/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

More modern version is display: inline-flex;