# stack vertically inline input text html

Tags: html, css

These input text are already stacked vertically but they're not in-line along with the other text. Image:[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UicEL.png

```css
#advanced input[type="text"] {
    border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 15px; 
    padding: 5px 10px;   
    background-image: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 30%;
}
```

```html
<form action="https://google.com/search">
            <div id="advanced">
            Find pages with...<br/><br/>
            all these words:<input type="text" name="as_q">
            this exact word or phrase:<input type="text" name="as_epq">
            any of these words:<input type="text" name="as_oq">
            none of these words:<input type="text" name="as_eq">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Advanced Search">
        </form>
```

What made it stack vertically was exactly the code:

```
  display: block;
  margin-left: 30%;
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks to have been answered previously [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686538/align-labels-in-form-next-to-input) - something like this might work for you, adding `display:grid` to the parent element.

```css
#advanced input[type="text"] {
    border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 15px; 
    padding: 5px 10px;   
    background-image: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 30%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
#advanced {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
    grid-gap:10px;
}
#advanced.settings label       { text-align:left; }
#advanced.settings label:after { content: ":"; }
```

```html
<form action="https://google.com/search">
            Find pages with...<br/><br/>
            <div id="advanced">
            
            all these words:<input type="text" name="as_q">
            this exact word or phrase:<input type="text" name="as_epq">
            any of these words:<input type="text" name="as_oq">
            none of these words:<input type="text" name="as_eq">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Advanced Search">
        </form>
```