# USWDS - How to align form labels to the left of inputs?

Tags: css, forms, alignment, styling, uswds

I'm using the 
[U.S. Web Design System (USWDS)](https://designsystem.digital.gov/)
 in a project I'm working on, and I'm struggling with something that seems superficially like it should be quite simple: How can I align form labels so they appear to the left of their corresponding inputs, instead of above them?

Some other CSS libraries call this a [horizontal form](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#horizontal-form) but I've also seen it referred to as "inline" fields.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48386400/845210) it's possible to achieve the result I want using modern CSS Grid layout, but so far I haven't figured out how to make that play nicely with the USWDS styling, which [does not use CSS Grid.](https://github.com/uswds/uswds/issues/2564)

Can anyone help me to either:

- Create a horizontal form using some combination of USWDS components and [utility classes](https://designsystem.digital.gov/utilities/), or if that's impractical...
- Produce a horizontal form by overriding the USWDS styling with custom CSS, but without causing too much conflict or breaking with the standard?

Below is a simplified snippet of my HTML:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uswds@2.8.0/dist/css/uswds.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<form class="usa-form">
    <div class="usa-form-group">
        <label class="usa-label" for="somefield1">Sample label</label>
        <input class="usa-input" type="number" name="somefield1" value=0 />
    </div>
    <div class="usa-form-group">
        <label class="usa-label" for="somefield2">Another label</label>
        <input class="usa-input" type="number" name="somefield2" value=0 />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flex` on the `usa-form-group` to get them positioned next to each other as shown in this Code Sandbox, with some other minor touchups to the element margins https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-moon-q7i7f?file=/styles.css

Comment: Good tip - url seems to be inaccessible though

Comment: @rymanso Ran into the same thing, did some more digging and found https://designsystem.digital.gov/components/memorable-date/ which helped.